# Flutter package:web 0.5.1 keeps reinstalling himself

Tags: android, flutter

even if I remove it from pubspec.yaml and pubspec.lock, run flutter clean and then pub get, this package automatically get installed.

i tried reinstalling flutter and dart, deleting web package from every part of the project directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching your pubspec.yaml file would have been easier to help you.

But well, it's probably because you're using a package that depends on web 0.5.1.

You can check this list : https://pub.dev/packages?q=dependency%3Aweb